# How do I tell how good my exponential curve fit is in SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, exponential-distribution

I fit some data using Scipy:

```
param=expon.fit(data)
pdf_fitted=expon.pdf(x,loc=param[-2],scale=param[-1])
plot(x,pdf_fitted,'r')
hist(data,normed=1,alpha=.3,histtype='stepfilled')
```

And I get a curve that looks like this:

[image: Exponential fit to data]

How do I check how good the fit is (is there a parameter for this?). I'd like a number so I can compare different ways of fitting.

Comment: Simplest way to go is to use [MSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error).

Comment: Is this question on-topic for SO? It seems to be asking about goodness-of-fit parameters rather than actual programming?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there's a function for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard method, assuming your errors are normally distributed, is to use the sum of the squared residuals. This, you can turn into rigurours statistics using the chi² distribution.

```
values, edges = np.histogram(data, bins=np.sqrt(len(data)))
x = edges[:-1] + np.diff(edges)

pdf_fitted = expon.pdf(x, loc=param[0], scale=param[1])
residuals = values - pdf_fitted

print np.dot(residuals, residuals)
```

Or, if you prefer the RMS:

```
print np.dot(residuals, residuals) / len(residuals)
```